# Plotting large numbers with R, but not all numbers are being shown

Tags: r, graphics, data-visualization, bigdata

I am trying to render 739455 data point on a graph using R, but on the x-axis I can not view all those numbers, is there a way I can do that?

I am new to R.[image]

Thank you

Comment: Please try to clarify this question.  Do you want more x-axis ticks and for it to extend farther?.  Do you want to see each individual data point?  It's unclear what you're asking for.

Comment: Yes John you are correct, I want to see each point on x-axis, is it possible to view it?

Comment: Viewing 750k individual points on a single plot is a large task to ask. You could look at the alpha parameter in ggplot2 as a way to reduce the overplotting. Are there other variables in your dataset that could help you split this up into a few different plots? Look here for ggplot examples with alpha: http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_point.html

Comment: I have 750K points with pattern like (nodenumber, nodecount)

Comment: 750K individual (x, y) points or 750K individual x-values?  In other words, is the x-axis 750K "wide" or can the same x-value have multiple y-values?

Comment: It sounds like you want a tick mark on the x axis for each of the ~750k x values in your data. Let's say we give just one pixel to each tick mark. That's ~750k pixels wide. How big is your computer screen?

Comment: its like 750k x points and at max 500 y points

Comment: its a 17" Macbook bro with supported resolution of 1920 by 1200

Comment: What I meant was that to see each individual point, you're going to need an enormous screen. Perhaps the best way to visualize this data is to aggregate it? A histogram maybe?

Comment: how would histogram help in this case? please let me know

Comment: Could you maybe draw on a bit of paper (or in GIMP or equiv) something step closer from what you've attached here to what you want? I think it is still really unclear to all.

Comment: The point that Joran is trying to make (painfully) is that you won't ever be able to view all 750k points effectively. A histogram bins ranges like 700-750k for example, so you can look at it on a bin by bin basis rather than overall. If that's all you're trying to do - try hist(your_data)

Comment: ...or follow the [advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976397/data-visualization-tool-for-large-datasets/6976491#6976491) you got in your previous question and use hexbin.

Comment: Also, you can try `plot(density(node))`, which produces fabrolous plots.  :)  Others may chime in with their favorite kernel smoothers du jour.  Check out the options for density via `?density` - it's a good little function to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others suggested, try `hist`, `hexbin`, `plot(density(node))`, as these are standard methods for dealing with more points than pixels.  (I like to set `hist` with the parameter `breaks = "FD"` - it tends to have better breakpoints than the default setting.)

Where you may find some joy is in using the `iplots` package, an interactive plotting package.  The corresponding commands include `ihist`, `iplot`, and more.  As you have a Mac, the more recent `Acinonyx` package may be even more fun.  You can zoom in and out quite easily.  I recommend starting with the `iplots` package as it has more documentation and [a nice site](http://rosuda.org/iplots/).

If you have a data frame with several variables, not just `node`, then being able to link the different plots such that brushing points in one plot highlights them in another will make the whole process more stimulating and efficient.

That's not to say that you should ignore `hexbin` and the other ideas - those are still very useful.  Be sure to check out the options for hexbin, e.g. `?hexbin`.